# Python Immutable Tuple - What Am I Doing Wrong?

Tags: tuples, mutable

Apologies if this is obvious but I'm pretty new to Python and I cannot get my head around this problem. In the following code I have populated a tuple with a series of lists and I am trying to create a new list with items from this tuple. I was hoping that the final result will be that test_raw remains unchanged and test_working will look like the following:

```
[['aa', 1, 2, 99.5, ['bb', 1, 2, 27.2]],
 ['aa', 5, 5, 74.2, ['bb', 5, 5, 37]]]
```

However, in the process, I seem to be appending the 'bb' lists to my tuple as well. I thought that once a tuple is constructed, it cannot be changed but obviously not. Any idea what is happening?

```
test_raw = (['aa',1,2,99.5],
            ['bb',1,2,27.2],
            ['aa',5,5,74.2],
            ['bb',5,5,37])
test_working = []

for i in range(len(test_raw)):
   if test_raw[i][0] == "aa":
       test_working.append(test_raw[i])
for i in range(len(test_raw)):
   if test_raw[i][0] == "bb":
       for j in range(len(test_working)):
           if test_working[j][1:3] == test_raw[i][1:3]:
               test_working[j].append(test_raw[i])
               break
print(test_raw)
(['aa', 1, 2, 99.5, ['bb', 1, 2, 27.2]], ['bb', 1, 2, 27.2], ['aa',.....)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not appending to the tuple itself, but the lists inside tuple.  I won't debug your code for you but when you run your code, you'll notice that your first list (originally `['aa',1,2,99.5]`) has a new element in it (`['bb', 1, 2, 27.2]`)

You aren't appending to the tuple, you are just changing the lists that are inside that tuple

Consider this simple example

```
my_tuple = (1,2,3, [4,5,6])
my_tuple[3].append(7)
```

This doesn't add onto `my_tuple`, just the list that is the last element of it

Comment: Thanks for the advice. It's pretty obvious now. I just couldn't see it at the time. I can see now that if I don't want my raw data to change, I should set test_raw to be a tuple of tuples rather than a tuple of lists.

Comment: @JC_RMB yes that's a perfectly good method of ensuring that your data remain unchanged